# Find the function that minimizes $\int_{0}^{1}e^{-(y'-x)}+(1+y)y'dx$

Tags: calculus-of-variations

> Suppose among all the continuously differentiable functions $y(x), x\in \mathbb{R}$, with $y(0)=0$ and $y(1)=\frac{1}{2},$ the function $y_0(x)$ minimizes the functional,
>
> $$\displaystyle\int_{0}^{1}e^{-(y'-x)}+(1+y)y'dx$$
> Find the value of $y(\frac{1}{2}).$

**My attempt:** Using Euler's equation $F_y-\frac{d}{dx}F_{y'}=0$ here $F(x,y,y')=e^{-(y'-x)}+(1+y)y'$, we get

$$\implies y'-\frac{d}{dx}(-e^{x-y'}+1+y)=0$$
$$\implies y''-y'e^{y'-x}-1=0$$ (after simplification)

But now I am stuck as I don't know how to proceed from here? Please help me out. Thanks!

Comment: your last formula is false ? $\frac{d}{dx}(e^{x-y'}) = 0$

Comment: I'm not sure how you got your result, but I got

$$\frac{d}{dx} \bigg( \frac{ \partial F }{ \partial y'} \bigg) - \frac{ \partial F }{ \partial y} = -e^{ x - y' } (1 - y'' )$$

Comment: sorry my bad...thanks guys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you made a mistake going from the first line of your equation to the second:

$$
y' - \frac{d}{dx}(-e^{x-y'} + 1 + y) = 0 \\
\Rightarrow  (1 - y'')e^{x-y'} = 0
$$

Which is only true if $y'' \equiv 1$. Which gives $y = \frac 12 x^2$ with the boundary conditions, and so $y\left(\frac 12\right) = \frac 18$. I haven't checked whether or not this is actually a minimum, you'll have to compute the second variation to get that.